# Python - Copying csv files to Dataframe (but skip sub-folders)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using the below code to read a set of csv files from a folder to a Dataframe. However this folder has a sub-folder along with these csv files. How could I skip the sub-folder and only read the csv file. The below code throws an error when I try to run this folder that has a sub-folder.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import time

path = r'/Users/user/desktop/Sales/'


allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
sale_df = pd.concat(list_)
sale_df

Error message : IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 
'/Users/user/desktop/Sales/2018-05-03/20180503000513-kevin@store.com- 
190982.csv-1525305907670.csv'
```

Could anyone assist on this. Thanks

**EDIT:** The issue is the subdirectory has the extension '.csv' present in the subdirectory name.

**EDIT in code**

```
path =r'/Users/user/desktop/Sales/2018-05-03/'
files_only = [file for file in 
glob.glob('/Users/user/desktop/Sales/2018-05-03/*.csv') if not 
os.path.isdir(file)]
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(files_only,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
sale_df = pd.concat(list_)
sale_df['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
sale_df.append(frame)
sale_df
```

Get the below error

ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Could you please assist. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion uses `glob.glob` to get a list of all matching files/directories that match the specified string, then uses the `os` module to check each matching file/directory to make sure it is a file. It returns a list of ONLY files that match the glob.glob().

```
import glob
import os

files_only = [file for file in glob.glob('/path/to/files/*.ext') if not os.path.isdir(file)]
```

You can then use the files_only list in your read_csv loop.

So in your code:

```
files_only = [file for file in glob.glob('/Users/user/desktop/Sales/2018-05-03/*.csv') if not os.path.isdir(file)]
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file in files_only:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
sale_df = pd.concat(list_)
sale_df['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
sale_df.append(frame)
sale_df
```

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code in the original message, however get an error "ValueError: No objects to concatenate".. Could you please assist.

Comment: Does files_only produce a list of all .csv files? I think your issue is in your file loop, you need to have "for file in files_only" and then when you have the "df = pd.read_csv" line, your first argument needs to be "file" instead of "files_only". I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Got another error now as below

**bold** TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not module **bold**.

This points to line "sale_df['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)" in the above code. Any advice on this. Thanks..

Comment: I think you'd need to open another question as I'm now just debugging your code. The issue is probably that the variable 'csv' in os.path.basename(csv) has not been defined anywhere. If my answer solved your issue, please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You call `allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")`, even when your `path` variable ends with a forward slash. That way, it ends up as `allFiles = glob.glob("/Users/user/desktop/Sales//*.csv")`.
See if fixing that helps with your error.

Comment: The issue is because the OP has a subdirectory called "something.csv" so the "*.csv" string in the glob.glob() call is finding the directory as well as all matching files.

Comment: Also, multiple forward slashes are legit and will be treated as a single one. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/77869